# How can I determine whether or not I should ask for a raise, and how do I approach my boss with this?

Tags: salary, raise

I started a job as a car parts driver (something to work around my school schedule). We recently lost our manager and the warehouse assistant (stock boy) so they now have me doing stock, invoices, dispatching, and delivering parts. I do at least double the work as all the parts drivers but still get paid the same as them.

How can I determine whether or not I should ask for a raise, and how do I approach my boss with this?

Comment: "Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals," so this question is likely to be closed. If you were instead asking "now that my work has changed, how do I go about asking for the higher pay associated with the new work?", that question would be on-topic.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Equal Pay, Equal Work act but I wouldn't go down that route.

Comment: FYI:It doesn't mean a thing if you do 100 times more work than anybody else. What matters is how much money do you make for the company. If you truly are twice as valuable as anyone else then your manager would notice and take steps to make sure you don't leave.  Also, many, if not most employees think they do twice as much as anyone else when the reality is that they may even be doing less or at best as much as anyone else. Once again, it's up to your manager to take notice or for you to make sure your manager takes notice.

Comment: @Dunk The problem is that we don't have a manager right now other than a temp that doesn't have the authority to give a raise. So there is no boss to approach. The temp manager has praised me for how much I have been doing, but every time I ask to talk to a supervisor it never happens. Basically at this point I am tired of doing all the extra work while the other drivers are sitting around talking (literally)

Comment: Schedule a review with the immediate manager during the normal period for your company (e.g. 6 months) and ask for a promotion/raise based on reasonable points (e.g. if you're effectively doing tasks beyond the standard job description). How do you know that your temp manager isn't authorized to give raises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you want to look at what your job description is. If this goes outside the job description then you have a argument to why you shouldn't be required to do it. In all of my experience you're not going to be better off trying to go this route unless it's a big company and a higher level position.

If you're looking for more pay for the extra job responsibilities then be a diplomat. Set up a formal meeting with your boss. Don't make it informal or they will not take you as seriously. Know what you want, know what you'll settle for. Make sure you directly ask for more compensation rather than hinting. Explain that you're excited about the new responsibilities but you'd also like your compensation to reflect your extra efforts.

I've made mistakes with the way I did the meeting (I did an informal meeting and came unprepared) and lost out on extra compensation before.